# About the Text Rank summary

Tags: summary, textrank

How can I select the number of sentences for the text rank summary? I want to know after applying the text rank algorithm to the text data set, How many sentences or how much portion of the text (standard) for the text rank summary.

Comment: Which library are you using? For example, in the Python `pytextrank` library the [`summary()`] method has a parameters `limit_sentences` for this purpose.